# Oracle SQL to include null dates in where clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following data:

```
id | actual_start
 1 | (null)
 2 | 03/03/2014
 3 | 27/03/2014
```

I want to be able to use a use input which will select all dates including and after the date input, but the nulls are causing me a problem.  I only want the nulls included if the user leaves the input blank.

This is what I have:

```
where actual_start >= nvl(to_date('&start_date','dd/mm/yyyy'), to_date('01/01/2000', 'dd/mm/yyyy'))
```

This is fine for when the user does actually enter a date.  However, if the user leaves it blank, then I get this:

```
id | actual_start
 2 | 03/03/2014
 3 | 27/03/2014
```

which is no good.

The other idea I had was to try:

```
where (actual_start >= nvl(to_date('&start_date','dd/mm/yyyy'), to_date('01/01/2000', 'dd/mm/yyyy'))
or actual_start is null)
```

but this always includes the nulls - i.e. it works for the user inputting nothing, but if the user inputs 20th March, it returns:

```
id | actual_start
 1 | (null)
 3 | 27/03/2014
```

which isn't okay.

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: so if nothing is keyed by user, do you just expect the null record or all records?

Comment: I am sorry but I did not get what you want to achieve. Do you want nulls or not? I understood you want them but comment after the last query is opposite.

Comment: Sorry guys,  I only want the nulls included if the user leaves the input blank.

Comment: So if user inputs '' you only want the null records displayed.  Anything with a date would not be displayed. Correct?

Comment: If &start_date is null then you want nulls, otherwise skip them?

Comment: If the user inputs a date, then I only want dates after that date.  If the user inputs a null, I want all records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
where nvl(actual_start, to_date('01/01/2000', 'dd/mm/yyyy')) >=
 nvl(to_date('&start_date','dd/mm/yyyy'), to_date('01/01/2000', 'dd/mm/yyyy'))
```

Although it has side-effect that index for `actual_date` column cannot be used, therefore may potentially lead to performance problems on large datasets.

**Update:** The other one you can use is your second condition slightly modified:

```
where actual_start >= 
 nvl(to_date('&start_date','dd/mm/yyyy'), to_date('01/01/2000', 'dd/mm/yyyy'))
or nvl('&start_date',actual_start) is null
```